# Send file or data directly to specific email id without opening the email chooser in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to desidn an application in which, I want to send any data, file or images as attachment directly to the specific email address without opening the gmail or email chooser in android.(Every user form details on submit button should reach to this ak2special@gmail.com without showing gmail or other email app).
It is kind of application submission form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a Or, better yet, have your Web server send the email.

Comment: can you please help me , where to specify the email address of the recipient and hw to attach file or image to it ?